# How many numbers can we choose so that no two differ by 2 or 5?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-theory

We choose some numbers from the set $\{1, 2, ..., 100\}$.

What is the largest possible number of numbers from the set that can be chosen so that no two of the chosen numbers vary by 2 or 5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the numbers modulo 7, i.e. the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ with the end looping back to the beginning. Among these numbers, we can pick up to three such that no pair differs by 2 or 5:

> firstly, three is attainable by picking $\{1,2,5\}$. To show that we can't pick more than three, assume WLOG that $1$ is among the numbers we pick. Then $3$ and $6$ can't be picked, and at most one in each pair $\{2,4\},\{5,7\}$ can be picked, so we have a maximum possible of three.

Now split the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$ into subsets of length 7. Our full set of chosen numbers can then contains up to three elements from each of the thirteen subsets $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\},\{8,9,10,11,12,13,14\},\dots,\{85,86,87,88,89,90,91\}$, and how many elements from the remaining set of length 9?

> In the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, we can choose at most five numbers such that no pair differs by 2 or 5: for example, $\{1,2,5,8,9\}$.

So the final answer is

> $3\times13+5=44$.